# Binding in code-behind

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I want to bind an IEnumerable to an ItemsControl. Here is the code in XAML that works:

```
<ItemsControl Name="SearchItemsControl" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=SearchResult}" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" BorderThickness="0" Background="{StaticResource PopUpContentGradientBrush}" VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" >
```

I want to do it from code-behind, and this is my code:

```
Binding binding = new Binding("SearchResult");
binding.Source = SearchResult;
```

And in BeginInvoke of a dispatcher:

```
SearchItemsControl.SetBinding(ItemsControl.ItemsSourceProperty, binding);
```

Here's the error I get in the Otput tab of VS:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 40 : BindingExpression path error: 'SearchResult' property not found on 'object' ''WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2' (HashCode=14814649)'. BindingExpression:Path=SearchResult; DataItem='WhereSelectEnumerableIterator`2' (HashCode=14814649); target element is 'ItemsControl' (Name=''); target property is 'ItemsSource' (type 'IEnumerable')
```

SearchResult is a property in my View-Model, which is of type IEnumerable. The control's name in XAML is SearchItemsControl.

Why is this code not working?

Here's the property:

```
private IEnumerable<SearchResultModel> _searchResult;

public IEnumerable<SearchResultModel> SearchResult
    {
        get { return _searchResult; }
        set
        {
            _searchResult = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("SearchResult");
        }
    }
```

First, SearchResult was ObservableCollection, but the same error appeared and I changed it to IEnumaberable.

Comment: First off, you should show some source more. Then, probably you are attempting to bind to a Linq query (which is not observable). Finally, it looks suspicious the binding above: is it your instance named SearchResult as well as its property?

Comment: @MarioVernari I added some code, please check. There is no need of plus code, because I show the xaml which already works. I just need the c# equivalent.

Comment: I'd ask you more about the "binding.Source" set to SearchResult. Are you sure that's correct? Try to remove it, or check what is the correct source used in the XAML.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to remove

```
binding.Source = SearchResult;
```

otherwise it mean that your ItemsControl get a new "DataContext" SearchResult and should bind the ItemsSource to a Property SearchResult of your object SearchResult.

edit: the following would work but is not the same as you did in xaml

```
Binding binding = new Binding(".");
binding.Source = SearchResult;
```

Comment: If I remove it, I don't get an error in the console, but when the itemscontrol loads, I can't see the items in it. It's empty. Just like it would be when I won't bind it to anything.

Comment: the good thing is when binding not work on wpf then there are just 2 options: 1st: wrong DataContext 2nd wrong binding Expression. Simply use Snoop (http://snoopwpf.codeplex.com/) to check your datacontext and binding at runtime. pls post your results